# rsync: chown "/some-destionation-path/.somefile.jpg.pY2TRG" failed: Permission denied (13)

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync, zfs

I'm doing `rsync -rlptoghv` for transferring a folder from XFS to ZFS. Usually, no problems arise. But sometimes, for some files (and I can't find a pattern), rsync fails to sync file permissions and dates and throws error.

For example, for file destination `/some-destionation-path/somefile.jpg` I get `rsync: chown "/some-destionation-path/.somefile.jpg.pY2TRG" failed: Permission denied (13)`

I really don't understand what's with that file name, it feels like a temporary file used for transfer. I looked over many similar questions but none involve this temporary file name and don't seem to apply to my case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In these instances it's almost always that the target `rsync` process has insufficient permissions to write to the parent directory.

In your example this would be `/some-destionation-path/`, and so the temporary file `.somefile.jpg.pY2TRG` could not be created.

Incidentally, rather than `-rlptoghv` you might as well use `-ahv` (the `-a` is `--archive`, which corresponds to `-rlptgoD`). It's easier to read and considerably easier to type.